# Counting into an array and writing to text file xcode

Tags: c, xcode, multidimensional-array, count, file-writing

Hi I am trying to count in note data from keyboard and write the data to a text file which will subsequently be read out of and played back as notes.

I seem to only be able to write one line of numbers to the text file and help would be most appreciated.  Sorry i still have some of my function code included in the global.

```
    #define SEQ_NOTENUM 8
    #define SEQ_NUM 2
    //  structures //

    typedef struct
    {
         int notenumber;
         int velocity;
    }NoteData;

    typedef struct
    {
        float frequency;
        float amplitude;
    } OscData;

    // functions //

     float mtof(int note);


    // originally in main //

    OscData noteToOsc(NoteData note);
    int setcount, count;
    int currentset;
    OscData osc;

    int main()

    {
        int key, vel;
        NoteData sequence[SEQ_NUM][SEQ_NOTENUM];
        OscData noteToOsc(NoteData note);
        FILE* Sequence1;

        // START PROGRAM RECORD -- WRITE an IF/ELSE to run program -   
      dummy line atm//
        aserveGetVelocity();


        Sequence1 = fopen ("sequence1.txt", "w");

        if (Sequence1 == NULL)

         {
             printf("file Error\n");
         }

         else
          {
                    for(setcount = 0; setcount < SEQ_NUM; setcount++)
             {
                printf("--- Please enter sequence %d (%d notes)...\n",
    setcount, SEQ_NUM);



                count = 0;

                while(count < SEQ_NOTENUM)
                 {
                      key = aserveGetNote();
                      vel = aserveGetVelocity();

                    if(vel > 0)
                     {
                         sequence[setcount][count].notenumber = key;
                         sequence[setcount][count].velocity = vel;

                fprintf(Sequence1, "note %d - %d/%d\n", count, key,
     vel);
                count++;

            }

            fclose(Sequence1);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    }
```

Comment: What language is this written in? Without a proper tag it's unlikely you'll get an answer

Comment: sorry i thought i did.. oops.  It's in C and just added the tags

Comment: Have you tried temporarily replacing `fprintf` with `printf` (i.e., redirecting the output to stdout instead of the file), to check if the issue might be something other than the file output?

Comment: @BrentKerby I have tried that and there seems to be no issue. It prints out 2x 8 note numbers and velocity numbers with no issues, any other ideas it's driving me crazy haha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code's indentation is messed up, obscuring the fact that `fclose(Sequence1)` is closing the file after only one pass through the inner loop. You probably want to move that to somewhere further down.